# One-to-one, self-referencing, bi-directional relationship

Tags: php, doctrine

I'm trying to create a one-to-one, self-referencing, bi-directional relationship (*wow*) with an entity, `Revision`, that looks like this:

```php
/**
 * @Entity()
 * @Table(name="rev")
 */
class Revision extends BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $comment;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Revision", inversedBy="parent")
     * @JoinColumn(name="revision_of", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $revisionOf;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Revision", mappedBy="revisionOf")
     */
    protected $parent;
}
```

Without the `parent` property, everything works fine. When I add that property, both relationships return `null`.

The immediate question is: can what I'm trying to do be accomplished in Doctrine? If so, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I want to do the same thing but I separated the relation with 2 oneToOne self-referencing and I still get issues.

Comment: never mind the issues, I had a typo, and it works if I do 2 separate uni-directional relation on 2 different columns with same referencedColumnName, but I still wonder about the bidirectional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: this is not possible. As bksunday said, you need two columns to accomplish this behavior.

Unfortunately, this requires some data duplication.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it with this one

```
oneToOne:
  previous:
    targetEntity: Change
    mappedBy: next
    joinColumn:
      name: id
      referencedColumnName: next_id
  next:
    targetEntity: Change
    inversedBy: previous
```

Comment: This issue could be useful to follow in future https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/3752

Answer (score 0):

When you have bi-directional relationship, you have to manage both sides

In this case

```
$revision->setRevisionOf($revisionOf);
$revisionOf->setParent($revision);
```

[Doctrine Working with associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html)

```
In the case of bi-directional associations you have to update the fields on both sides:
```